# How to change images cross dissolve xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to changes background images in a nice way like cross dissolve...

I manage to let the image change within 3 seconds.

Can you help me with a code to let it change in a nice way?

```
var timer = Timer()
var counter = 0

@IBOutlet weak var imageBG: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    repated()
}

func repated() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updatecounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func updatecounter() {
counter += 1
 if counter == 14 {
    counter = 1
 }

 imageBG.image = UIImage(named: "\(counter).png")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Into your `upodatecounter` you can use an UIView transition like this:

```
@objc func updatecounter() {
  counter += 1
  if counter == 14 {
     counter = 1
  }

  UIView.transition(with: imageBG,
      duration:3.0,
      options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
      animations: { self.imageBG?.image = UIImage(named: "\(counter).png") },
      completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much really appre